# nodejs ldap authentication failure

Tags: node.js, ldapjs

I am using the activedirectory npm package for authenticating to the activedirectory in the enterprise. Finding trouble authenticating, whereas I have done this multiple times before in other softwares.

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: 'ldap://<ldap server>:389',

            baseDN:'DC=ads,DC=dwdwdw,DC=com',
            bindDN: 'CN=dddd,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Process,DC=ads,DC=dwdwdw,DC=com',
            bindCredentials: 'vBAX5y5@',
            includeMembership:['user'],
             referrals: {
                 enabled: false,
                 excluded: [ ]
               },
               attributes: {

                   user: [ 'sAMAccountName' ],
                   group: [ 'distinguishedName' ]
                 },
               //filter: '(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user)(|(samaccountname={{username}})(mail={{mail}})))'
                 //filter: '(&(objectcategory=*)(|(samaccountname={{username}})))'

             }

var sAMAccountName = 'sss';
var password = 'password';
var username = sAMAccountName;
ad.authenticate(sAMAccountName, password, function(err, auth) {
  if (err) {
   console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
   return;
 }
```

when I run this nodejs script, I get the below error :

> ERROR: {"lde_message":"80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580\u0000","lde_dn":null}

Safe to say, I have no idea what I am doing.

But I do know that the searchAttribute should be 'sAMAccountName' - how do i put this in the config?

I also know that when I substitute the username of 'sss' with its DN i.e.

```
var username = 'CN=<full name of user>,OU=InfoWorker,OU=People,DC=ads,DC=dwdwdw,DC=com';
```

, it authenticates perfectly.

I have used usertodnmapping while enabling LDAP on MongoDB successfully.

```
userToDNMapping: |-
  [
        {
         match: "(.+)",
         ldapQuery: "dc=ads,dc=dwdwdw,dc=com??sub?(samAccountName={0})"
        }
       ]
```

But I just cannot seem to find the equivalent of it to use in activedirectory package. Could you please help me with it?

I would not mind using ldapjs as well. I just haven't had much success with that either. I just want to get authenticated in with the username, and get the username's group memberships.

Comment: Please refer to the solution below https://stackoverflow.com/a/60629571/5894292