# ldapauth-fork InvalidCredentialsError

Tags: node.js, ldap, ldapauth

I am trying to authenticate user against LDAP by using ldapauth-fork. I am having a problem with LDAP Admin account, while I know that it is right and works fine with LDAP browser but I am not able to make it work with ldapauth-fork.

```
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
  var LdapAuth = require('ldapauth-fork');
  var username= 'usernameToSearch';
  var password= 'userPassword';

  var ldap = new LdapAuth({
    url: 'ldap://......',
    bindDN: 'sAMAccountName=AdminName,OU=Domian,DC=domain,DC=local',
   bindCredentials: 'AdminPassword',
    searchBase: 'OU=Domain,DC=domian,DC=local',
    searchFilter: '(sAMAccountName={{' + username + '}})',
    reconnect: true
  });

  ldap.authenticate(username, password, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'authentication failed'
      });
    } else if (!user.uid) {
      console.log("user not found Error");
      res.send({
        success: false,
        message: 'authentication failed'
      });
    } else if (user.uid) {
      console.log("success : user " + user.uid + " found ");
    }
  });
```

Here is the error that am getting

> InvalidCredentialsError: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment:
> AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
>
> lde_message: '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment:
> AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580\u0000',   lde_dn: null

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you find solution for it ? if so kindly post it as a answer

Comment: Sorry it's to late. Will tomorrow share it

Comment: can you provide the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [activedirectory2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) library over npm, I tried with ldapauth-form but could get a successful result

It has a number of functions to get work done such as

- authenticate
- findUser

> Config code

```
const AD = require('activedirectory2').promiseWrapper;
const config = { url: 'ldap://dc.domain.com',
           baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
           username: 'username@domain.com',
           password: 'password' }
const ad = new AD(config);
```

> for #authenticate

```
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
var username = 'john.smith@domain.com';
var password = 'password';

ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
 if (err) {
   console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
   return;
 }

if (auth) {
 console.log('Authenticated!');
}
else {
 console.log('Authentication failed!');
}
});
```

> similarly for #finduser

```
// Any of the following username types can be searched on
var sAMAccountName = 'username';
var userPrincipalName = 'username@domain.com';
var dn = 'CN=Smith\\, John,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com';

// Find user by a sAMAccountName
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
ad.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
if (err) {
 console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
 return;
}

if (! user) console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
 else console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
});
```